# Server side fix for receiving string containing '&'(ampersand)

Tags: java, servlets, url-encoding

We have already shipped a client (.NET WinForms) application which sends customer data to Java server. While most of the data sent by client are accepted at server side, some records are truncated because of the presence of `&` character in it, as client sends raw `&` and do not URL encode it,  we have fixed it by using the below code:

```
string dataBefore="A & B";
string dataBefore = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(dataBefore);
```

It is impossible for us to update all the client applications(which are already shipped) and we are thinking of a server side fix.

With the help of Fiddler, we have made sure the data has left client in full, but when server reads as below:

```
//in java
String dataReceied=request.getParameter("data");
```

it gets truncated if data contains `&`

Could someone help us suggesting a server side(java) fix for this? Is it possible to access the request stream in java(instead of `request.getParameter()`)?

Comment: Are the requests sent using POST or GET?

Comment: @pap,   myRequest.Method = "POST";

                // Set the content type to a FORM
                myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";  So it is POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get access to the raw query string using `HttpServletRequest.getQueryString()` ([javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString%28%29)), which:

> returns a `String` containing the query string or null if the URL contains no query string. **The value is not decoded by the container**.

You can them perform manual decoding on that string, instead of using `getParameter()`.

@Wesley's idea of using `getParameterMap()` may not be useful, because you don't know which order the parameters were supplied in.

I'd suggest implementing this logic as a servlet filter, to decouple the fixing of the broken parameters from your actual servlet logic. This would involve writing a custom subclass of `HttpServletRequestWrapper` which overrides `getParameter()` and manuyally decodes the query string. Your servlet would then be able to use the `HttpServletrequest` API as though everything was tickety boo.

Comment: Thank you, we will implement this solution

Answer (score 0):

It is cut off because *&* signifies a new URL parameter in a request like this:
google.com?query=java&page=2. Java converts all these parameters to a Map, so that's where it goes wrong.

Have you tried iterating through request.getParameterMap()? The remaining data is most likely in the name of the next parameter. If that does not work, check out [the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) of HTTPServletRequest to see if there is another way to get your data.

Good luck!

PS How angry are you guys at the intern that wrote & shipped that client? That sounds messed up!